# Google search does not show my website

Tags: sitemap, google-search

I already added two versions: one with www, and the other without www, both pointing to same location.  I set the non-www as the preferred version.  I add sitemap only to the non-www version.  I added all the links in the sitemap.  Then still my sitemap index status is Pending.  I have an article that was current and relevant, but when I search for that keyword in google search, i ended already on the last search page, still my website doesn't appear.  However those websites which are not even related to my search keyword appear.  It's a bit frustrating cause I am confident my page is relevant and properly created, however Google still doesn't show it in the search results :(
Is there anything I still need to do?

Answer (score -1):

It takes a couple of days for Google to crawl through and update the results after you make each change. Wait a couple of days and see what happens.

Comment: i guess i have to wait then